# Double cursor on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: desktop-environments

I experiencing a problem with my ubuntu 15.10
A few seconds After login the login screen reappear and i have two cursors with a bizarre behavior

How can i fix that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in and out again or lock/unlock with `CTRL` + `L`? This might reset your cursor to normal. It is a workaround.

Comment: Yes i did it does not work

Comment: What display adapter are you using?

Comment: I am usine lightdm

Comment: I noticed that the login screen is an xfce4 While i have uninstalled this environment for keeping just kde